# How can I get the parameterized-type class from a parameterized-type method argument?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameters

Consider this contrived class:

```
import java.util.List;
public class Test {
    public String chooseRandom(List<String> strings) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When using reflection to inspect this method, how can I get the `Class` object representing `java.lang.String` (or even the string `"java.lang.String"`) when looking at the arguments for `chooseRandom`?

I know that Java erases types at compile-time, but they must still be in there, since `javap` can print them properly. Running `javap` on this compiled class results in:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
  public java.lang.String chooseRandom(java.util.List<java.lang.String>);
}
```

The parameterized type for `java.util.List` (`java.lang.String`) is definitely available... I just can't find out what it is.

I've tried this:

```
Class clazz = [grab the type of chooseRandom's parameter list's first argument];
String typeName = clazz.getName();
TypeVariable[] genericTypes = clazz.getTypeParameters();
if(null != genericTypes && 0 < genericTypes.length)
{
    boolean first = true;
    typeName += "<";
    for(TypeVariable type : genericTypes)
    {
        if(first) first = false;
        else typeName += ",";

        typeName += type.getTypeName();
    }

    typeName = typeName + ">";
}
```

This gives me a `typeName` of `java.util.List<E>`. What I'm hoping for is `java.util.List<java.lang.String>`.

I've read a few other questions and answers on SO and none of them really seem to answer this question, or if they do, there is no working code associated with them and the explanations are ... thin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's type erasures mean that the "true type" of the parameter (`java.util.List`) doesn't contain the generic type information. You can't simply use `Method.getParameterTypes()[i]` and expect to extract the generic parameter types (`String`, in this case) from there. Instead, you have to use `Method.getGenericParameterTypes` which returns a whole menagerie of implementations of the somewhat useless `java.lang.reflect.Type` interface.

Ultimately, here is code that gives an example of how to do *everything* I was trying to do:

```
public String getDataType(Class clazz)
{
    if(clazz.isPrimitive())
        return clazz.getName();

    if(clazz.isArray())
        return getDataType(clazz.getComponentType()) + "[]";

    String typeName;
    if("java.lang".equals(clazz.getPackage().getName()))
        typeName = clazz.getName().substring(10);
    else
        typeName = clazz.getName();

    return typeName;
}

public String getDataType(Type type)
{
    if(type instanceof Class)
        return getDataType((Class)type);

    if(type instanceof ParameterizedType)
    {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)type;
        StringBuilder typeName = new StringBuilder(getDataType(pt.getRawType()));

        Type[] specificTypes = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
        if(null != specificTypes && 0 < specificTypes.length)
        {
            typeName.append("<");
            for(int j=0; j<specificTypes.length; ++j)
            {
                if(j > 0)
                    typeName.append(",");

                typeName.append(getDataType(specificTypes[j]));
            }

            typeName.append(">");
        }

        return typeName.toString();
    }

    return "[" + type + ", a " + type.getClass().getName() + "]";
}

public void getMethodSignature(Method m)
{
    System.out.print(getDataType(m.getGenericReturnType());
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(method.getName());
    System.out.print("(");
    Type[] parameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
    if(null != parameterTypes && 0 < parameterTypes.length)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<parameterTypes.length; ++i)
        {
            if(0<i) System.out.print(",");
            System.out.print(getDataType(parameterTypes[i]));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(")");
}
```

I've left-out the parts of the signature that aren't that exciting and would just clutter things up: visibility and other flags, the exception types, etc.

The above code can properly decode the type signature of the *real* method I was trying to plumb for more information:

```
protected void parseLocalesHeader(String string,
                                  java.util.TreeMap<Double,java.util.ArrayList<java.util.Locale>> treeMap)
```

Note that this currently doesn't handle a few implementations of `Type`, such as `TypeVariable` (that's the one that looks like `<T extends Serializable>`). I'll leave that as an exercise for anyone who wants to follow in my footsteps. The above code should get you on your way.

Comment: Kudos to @DavidConrad for posting his answer that got me thinking along the right lines to write this (more complete) one.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`getGenericParameterTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--) and [`getActualTypeArguments`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments--) methods:

```
Method m = Test.class.getMethod("chooseRandom", List.class);
Type t = m.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
// we know, in this case, that t is a ParameterizedType
ParameterizedType p = (ParameterizedType) t;
Type s = p.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // class java.lang.String
```

In practice, if you didn't know that there was at least one parameter and it was generic and had one type argument, of course, you would have to add some checks.

Comment: This got my brain where I needed it to be. At first, I accepted this answer, but I'm going to post my own answer because it really is much more fully fleshed-out.

Answer (score 0):

[`Method.getGenericParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes()) will return a [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) for generic arguments, which can be inspected to extract its type arguments.  So `Test.class.getMethod("chooseRandom", List.class).getGenericParameterTypes()` should return a single-element array containing a `ParameterizedType`.